# Referencing objects (in array)

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object like this in javascript:

```
var events = 
[
{
 id: 'a',
 title: 'Event 1 title'
},
{
 id: 'b',
 title: 'Event 2 title'
}
];
```

In order to reference event b I have to know the index of the event b, which I could find out by looping through the array and checking what is the index of the event when event's id matches b.

Is there easier way to reference event b when I know the id property of the event?

Comment: No. you have to iterate through the array.

Answer (score 2):

> In order to reference event b I have to know the index of the event b

Not necessarily. You can use `Array.filter` to get the object you need without the need of knowing it's index.

```
var obj = events.filter(function(obj){
   return obj.id == "b";
})[0]
```

or you can also use `Array.prototype.find` which is new in ES6 like

```
var obj = events.find((obj) => obj.id == "b");
```

Comment: In es2015 there is `Array.prototype.find()` which might be more convenient.

Comment: @zerkms, I've included it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, don't store it as a list, store it as an object:

```
var events = {'a': 'Event title 1', 'b': 'Event title 2'}
```

and then use it like this:

```
events['a']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build an index over the ids of the objects in the list of events:

```
> var events = [{
...     id: 'a',
...     title: 'Event 1 title'
... }, {
...     id: 'b',
...     title: 'Event 2 title'
... }];
> var index = {};
> events.forEach(function(v, i) { index[v.id] = i; });
> index
{ a: 0, b: 1 }
> events[index['b']]
{ id: 'b', title: 'Event 2 title' }
```

Comment: i usually use it to speedy execute

Answer (score 0):

Check the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) for this method.

```
var result = $.grep(myArray, function(e){ return e.id == id; });
```

Comment: Please just let jquery die.

Comment: Yeah just let the most used JavaScript library die.

Comment: People forgot how to program without it. The modern vanilla JS solution is shorter than your code, but hey let's bring 80kb just for such a trivial task.

Comment: Vanilla JavaScript solution for this particular situation is shorter indeed. But for anything else is painfully longer. `document.getElementsByClassName('.test');` vs `$(".test");`

Comment: "for anything else" --- the "anything" part here is simply wrong. I could agree if it was "something"

Comment: Yes, a simple task as selecting child elements from a specified selector is trivial in jQuery. This doesn't happen in Vanilla. If you don't want to use it, fine, don't. But stop bashing it without any legitimate reason.

Comment: I believe his point was why using the heavy-weight jQuery when you can simply use the `Array.prototype.filter` method. Loading a DOM/Ajax library for filtering an object makes no sense.

Comment: I think saying that jQuery should die because in this solution it's not needed, is a bit far-fetched I would say.

Comment: @Isuckatprogramming well it isn't tagged jQuery and hence answering purely using a lib is a bit far-fetched too, I guess.

Comment: I stood corrected and my answer wasn't at all appropriate. His remark on jQuery (the library in general) is just unjustified. If you can write less code and do more, while maintaining readability, you should use it.